# checkbox submits same value independent wether box is checked or unchecked

Tags: php

my problem is that my e-mail form has a check box and it does not matter if the box is checked or not, it always transmits the same value, all other fields work ok, its just the checkbox I'm having problems. I tried several suggestions from this forum without luck, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!
I'm not too proficient in PHP.

```
<form method="post" action="contact-form-handler1.php">
   <div class= "form">
     <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" style="color:grey"></i>
     </span>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" 
required>
    </div><br>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw" style="color:grey"></i>
    </span>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email 
address" required>
    </div><br>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw" style="color:grey"></i>
   </span>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
   </div><br>
</div>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-fw" style="color:grey">
   </i></span>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="6" type= "text" name="message" 
placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
   </div><br>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
   <input class="form" type="hidden"  name="check" value="0">
      <input class="form" type="checkbox"  name="check" value="1"><span 
   </div>
   <br><br>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm"><span class="input-group-addon">
   <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw" style="color:grey"></i>
   </span>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" placeholder="For 
security, please type SECURE in this field">
   </div><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary send" type="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>

<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'info@xyz.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
empty($_POST['email']) ||
empty($_POST['phone']) || 
empty($_POST['message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
$check = $_POST['check']; 

// if data is posted, set value to 1, else to 0
$check = isset($_POST['check']) ? 1 : 0;
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}
if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'SECURE') {die('Wrong access code');
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the
Mail Handler. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: 
$email_address \n Message: \n $message \n Signup: $check"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.php');
}
```

?>

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It will make it easier for both you and us to read the code and follow the flow.

Comment: I can only find one checkbox in your form, which has the name `checkp`. However, you never get `checkp` in you PHP, you only get `check`, which is a hidden input field and not a checkbox.

Comment: I changed the indent and corrected the"checkp" to "check" as it was when I tried it

Comment: You can't have two inputs with the same name. What are you trying to solve with the hidden input? Remove the hidden input and it should work. (btw, you should indent the PHP as well.)

Comment: Hi Magnus, I had it without the hidden input and for some reason it didn't work, so I found the hidden input option in one of the forums. I did as you said and it worked today, maybe I was just too tired last night! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How checkboxes work is that they don't get sent at all if they aren't checked. If they are checked, they are sent with the defined value. That's why it's better to set the default value in your code instead (like you did with `isset()`).